# How to locate a QR code in the world with 2D information from a single camera?

Tags: opencv, qr-code

Let's say the world coordinates and the parameters of the camera are known, with the QR code in the image, is there any existing OpenCV package to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can detect a QR code in latest OpenCV, see [live_detect_qrcode.cpp](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/0f622206e48f6050536f00d47abf47c4a2d1824a/samples/cpp/live_detect_qrcode.cpp).

You should get also the QR contour. With some code, you should be able to get the 4 QR corners. For instance, you could use [approxPolyDP()](https://docs.opencv.org/4.0.0-beta/d3/dc0/group__imgproc__shape.html#ga0012a5fdaea70b8a9970165d98722b4c) to approxrimate the QR contour by 4 coordinates. Another solution is to try to fit 4 lines to the contour and compute the QR corners as the lines intersections.

Then, you can use [solvePnP()](https://docs.opencv.org/4.0.0-beta/d9/d0c/group__calib3d.html#ga549c2075fac14829ff4a58bc931c033d) to estimate the camera pose.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, although what I want to calculate is the world coordinate and the rotation matrix of QR code...